# Posting value using Auto Submit isn't working

Tags: javascript, php

I have a post value came from the another page and post to index2.php. I want to post again that value to autosubmit.php using auto submit script. But why isn't working?

Here's my code

index2.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$drop=$_POST['drop'];
$tier_two=$_POST['tier_two'];

echo'
<form method="post" action="autosubmitform.php" id="dateForm" name="dateForm">
<input name="drop" type="" value="'.$drop.'" style="background-color:blue;"><input name="tier_two" type="" value="'.$tier_two.'">
<input type="submit" name="editsubmit">
</form>';

echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("dateForm").submit(); // SUBMIT FORM
</script>';

}
?>
```

autosubmitform.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
if (isset($_POST['editsubmit'])) {
$drop=$_POST['drop'];
$tier_two=$_POST['tier_two'];

echo $drop; echo $tier_two;
}
echo'
<input name="drop" type="" value="'.$drop.'" style="background-color:red;"><input name="tier_two" type="" value="'.$tier_two.'">
<input type="submit" name="editsubmit">';
?>
```

Comment: is submit not working or submitting but not sending data???????

Comment: @rajeshkakawat not sending data

Comment: did you check your post value, var_dump($_POST['drop']) see what you get

Comment: @rajeshkakawat It echo's the right post value. But why I tried to echo that post value but nothing appears?

Comment: @rajeshkakawat string(10) "component1" . Component1 is my $drop value

Comment: what is file name autosubmitform.php or Autosubmit.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44999/discussion-between-rajesh-kakawat-and-user3097736)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changes in your code

```
   /*
    if you submit your form through javascript your button value is not submited
    so you have to click that by javascript to submit it value 
    */

 <script type="text/javascript">

   document.getElementsByName("editsubmit")[0].click(); // SUBMIT FORM
 </script>
```

Also move your echo code inside php because if it does'nt go inside `if` than your variable `$drop` and `$tier_two` remain undefine in your echo statement present outside `if`

```
if (isset($_POST['editsubmit'])) {
    $drop=$_POST['drop'];
    $tier_two=$_POST['tier_two'];

    echo $drop; 
    echo $tier_two;
    echo'
    <input name="drop" type="text" value="'.$drop.'" style="background-color:red;"><input name="tier_two" type="text" value="'.$tier_two.'">
    <input type="submit" name="editsubmit">';
}
```

Alternate solution for above PHP code

```
$drop = ''; 
$tier_two = ''; 
if (isset($_POST['editsubmit'])) {
    $drop=$_POST['drop'];
    $tier_two=$_POST['tier_two'];

    echo $drop; 
    echo $tier_two;

}
echo'
    <input name="drop" type="text" value="'.$drop.'" style="background-color:red;"><input name="tier_two" type="text" value="'.$tier_two.'">
    <input type="submit" name="editsubmit">';
```

Comment: great :)) thanks man ! I used this trick because of I'm having a big trouble using php session.

Answer (score 0):

user this script

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.forms['dateForm'].submit()

}
```

as follows

```
echo"<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
      document.forms['dateForm'].submit()

    }
</script>";
```

Comment: also nothing receive a post value in autosubmit.php

Comment: print your post varibles in autosubmit.php using print_r($_POST); and show me

Comment: one more your type attribute is blank in input fill it and try

Comment: what is output of autosubmit.php

Comment: only the input but doesn't have any data

Comment: that means value of input box has not set by your variable $drop and $tier_two in index2.php

Comment: I echo the post variable and nothing appears? echo $drop; echo $tier_two;

Comment: so thats the problem in your index2.php find that why they are not set

Comment: but when I tried this var_dump($_POST['drop']) I received string(10) "component1" . Component1 is my $drop value

Answer (score 0):

I hate not being able to comment. The only thing though is that some people can get caught half way through this.

If someone has javascript turned off, then they'll get stuck on this page with the raw data. Is there another way you could write this?

You could also just pass the values in the url (GET instead of POST) and encode the values if they need to be encrypted.